callbacks not getting called using NextAuth.js with CredentialsProvider
Issue is after successful authorize and return user + jwt token it's not getting in any of the callbacks
options for NextAuth are as follows:
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import base_url from '@/app/_util/StrapiConfig';

// Write options for NextAuth with providers, authorize and callbacks for Credentials provider here

export const options = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: 'Credentials',
            credentials: {
                email: { label: "Email", type: "text", placeholder: "Please enter your email" },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
            },
            async authorize(credentials, req) {
                const { email, password } = credentials;
                try {
                    fetch(base_url + `/auth/local`, {
                        headers: {
                            'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_TOKEN}`,
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        },
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            identifier: email,
                            password: password,
                        })
                    }).then(res => res.json()).then(response => {
                        const cond = response?.jwt !== null;
                        if(cond !== null) {
                            return response;
                        } else if(response.status === 403) {
                            throw new Error('User with these email is not registered!');
                            // redirect signup page
                        } else if(response.status === 401) {
                            throw new Error('Invalid credentials!');
                            // redirect login page
                        } else {
                            throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
                        }
                      })
                      .catch(error => {
                        
                      });
                } catch (error) {
                    
                }               
            }
        })
    ],
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
    },
    secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
    callbacks: {
        async session({session, user, token}) {
            console.log("session", session);
            session.user.email = user.email;
            return session;
        },
        async jwt({token, user}) {
            console.log("token", token);
            if(user) {
                token.user = user;
                token.jwt = user.jwt;
            }
            return token;
        },
    }
}

I'm getting user in authorize also getting 200 log in backend but not getting in any of callback niether session nor jwt
next.js app logs are as follows:
GET /api/auth/signin 200 in 654ms
POST /api/auth/callback/credentials 302 in 16ms
GET /api/auth/error?error=CredentialsSignin&provider=credentials 302 in 7ms
GET /api/auth/signin?error=CredentialsSignin 200 in 7ms

Backend log is as follows:
[2024-07-27 14:47:45.855] http: POST /api/auth/local (1283 ms) 200

I have watched n number of tutorials and everyone is doing the same, I have been stuck at this point for hours now!

Looks like the data flow in your example is wrong
Please change your authorize method like that
async authorize(credentials, req) {
    const { email, password } = credentials

    const res = await fetch(base_url + `/auth/local`, { // /auth/local ???
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_TOKEN}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            identifier: email,
            password: password,
        })
    })

    const user = await res.json()

    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error("Something went wrong!")
    }

    if (res.ok && user) {
        return user
    }

    return null
}

To be able to use our own session props, we need to add type folder at the root level of the project and put next-auth.d.ts file inside it
import { DefaultSession } from "next-auth"

declare module "next-auth" {
    interface User {
        id: string
        jwt: string
    }

    interface Session {
        user: User & DefaultSession["user"]
        expires: string
        error: string
    }
}

and then change your jwt callback (which runs after authorize method) like that
async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
    if (account && user) {
        token.id = "user-id" // for testing purposes, I do not know what kind of props your user response has
        token.jwt = user.jwt
    }

    return token
}

and finally change the session callback (which runs after jwt callback) like that
async session({ session, token }) {
    console.log("session => ", session)

    return {
        ...session,
        user: {
            ...session.user,
            id: token.id as string,
            jwt: token.jwt as string,
        },
        error: token.error,
    }
}

